# macbook pro for graphic design work

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am planning to purchase a macbook pro md101(mid 2012, non retina,13") for my graphic design and photography work while I am travelling. Can you please share your experiences with this model? Is it capable of handling photoshop, illustrator and premiere? I am still using cs5 but might upgrade to cc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [MacRumors](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/#Mac) lists nearly (all save the newest) laptops as do not buy

Comment: And [Apple Should Stop Selling 4 year old laptops](https://apple.slashdot.org/story/16/08/04/1331203/apple-should-stop-selling-four-year-old-computers) CC: @joojaa

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to buy something this old you might as well just buy a secondhand one (assuming from the given comments you aren't) and use the saved money to do some RAM/SSD upgrades.

But in general I personally find 13 inch **way** too small for graphic design or photography editing. I guess this is mostly opinion bases though. I work on my 15 inch macbook pro when I'm on the go and I already get annoyed by it's screensize.

Performance wise, yes it'll be able to handle photoshop and illustrator. My macbrook pro is from early 2010. I've upgraded RAM and switched to SSD and I don't have complaints at all. Wouldn't recommend it for seriously heavy stuff like video editing though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have a hp 15" laptop. I don't like how bulky it is. A reason for choosing 2012 model over the others is, it is the only model which can be upgraded(Ram/ssd) by the user later on.